# Uploading files to S3 using paperclip, IOError (closed stream) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am currently having issues uploading files to amazon S3 while using paperclip. It uploads half the files, and then chokes, with the error: `IOError (closed stream)` I have no idea what's causing this, any help would be really appreciated.

Here's the stack trace:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/connection.rb:41:in `request'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/connection.rb:52:in `request'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:69:in `request'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:88:in `put'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/object.rb:241:in `store'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:206:in `flush_writes'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:203:in `each'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:203:in `flush_writes'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:144:in `save'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:338:in `send'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:338:in `save_attached_files'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:331:in `each_attachment'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:330:in `each'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:330:in `each_attachment'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:337:in `save_attached_files'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/app/models/image.rb:56:in `store_image_dimensions_for_cropping'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/lib/cms_engine/acts/versioned.rb:127:in `save_with_versioning'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:188:in `transaction'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/lib/cms_engine/acts/versioned.rb:119:in `save_with_versioning'
/Users/adamcarlile/Sites/Rails/glews/vendor/plugins/cms-engine/lib/cms_engine/acts/versioned.rb:109:in `save'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/giraffesoft-resource_controller-0.6.5/lib/resource_controller/actions.rb:22:in `create'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1331:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/metal.rb:47:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:64:in `process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/Users/adamcarlile/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
```

Cheers
Adam

Comment: This will also happen if you have dragonfly and installs meta_request gem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is caused by a race condition between the ruby garbage collector and Tempfile.

Someone developed a patch for rails projects here: https://github.com/jwinky/ruby_tempfile_ioerror

Comment: I have the same issue with ruby 2.0.0.